# Adjust div to image size

Tags: css, image, html

normally, I used to adjust an image to a div depending of it's width and height attributes using background-image. Now I have the exactly opposite issue.

What I'm trying to do is adjust the div size to the image but with a maximum width and height. let's say that if image is 200x200, the div must be adjusted to this size but if image exceeds the 300x300, it must by limited.

Any idea of how should i do it?

Comment: Confirming, background image or img tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the `max-width` and `max-height` style properties to the image element.

Depending on what you need to do with the containing element, this might work:

```
<div>
    <div style="position: absolute;">Element content here</div>
    <img src="image.png" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you change "position: absolute" so that you get a centered image?

Answer (score 0):

What's the structure of your page?

I would guess you use something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
    #container {
        display: inline-block;
        border:1px solid blue;
        max-width:300px;
        max-height:300px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The question is that I'm using background-image for placing the image withing the div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size