# How can I write a text on an image inside a jumbotron using bootstrap 3.3?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

How to put a text inside an image using bootstrap 3.3.5. I want the image to be on the background.

Example = https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZIoi.png.

Comment: You need to post the code you are working with in a working example (HTML/CSS/JS) [mcve] and see > [jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000754/responsive-bootstrap-jumbotron-background-image

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('http://image.url/he.png');">
    <h2>Hello Heading Here</h2>
    <p>Some Paragraph Stuff Here</p>
</div>
```