# html text on responsive background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve the following:
[image]

Where there is a background image, and a text over it (text position is bootstrap offset-6 col-6)

And for it to be responsive.

The thing is, that unlike conventional background, I do care how the background image is truncated, I need the phone to be visible regardless of the width.

I tried: 
`background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;`

And the invisible `img` trick on [How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size)

In all the cases the phone gets truncated

Assistance will be appreciated

**Edit**:
As requested - the original div structure is:

```
<div id="hungry">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xl-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-xl-6">
        <p>Hungry doesn't always happen in the kitchen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have no problem changing it to whatever works...

Comment: Are you looking for CSS-only or is JavaScript OK? Also, are you using `.jumbotron` (as in the proposed solution)? And, is the picture taking the whole width of the screen or only the container size?

Comment: Whole width. I prefer CSS solution but a JS one will do (if it solves the problem) - currently I'm using a regular div all the width - can use jumbotron if it helps...

Comment: It's fine, I just wanted to figure out what was the HTML structure (is possible, post the necessary `div`s as part of the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution with JavaScript

I know this is not a CSS-only solution a I use JavaScript, but it could help as a temporary solution while we look for a CSS thing.

The HTML would be the same as you posted:

```
<div id="hungry">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xl-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-xl-6">
        <p>Hungry doesn't always happen in the kitchen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the div with id "hungry" would look like this:

```
#hungry {
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xasp.jpg') no-repeat center center ;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
}
```

And finally, with JavaScript (I used jQuery to make it easier), you resize the height of `#hungry` depending on the screen width:

```
// you know the size for your image
imageWidth = 1919;
imageHeight = 761;
imageProportion = imageHeight/imageWidth;

function resizeJumbo() {
    $("#hungry").css({ height: $(window).width() * imageProportion });
}

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    resizeJumbo();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeJumbo();
});
```

You can see a demo working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyfz0Lga/.

### Solution with CSS only

Just update the CSS for the hungry div a little:

```
#hungry {
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xasp.jpg') no-repeat center center ;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:20%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/hyfz0Lga/1/.

**Why `padding-top:20%` and `padding-bottom:20%`?**

Those values have to do with the size of the picture, and the proportion between them. In your case: width = 1919 and height = 761, so the proportion between width and height is (761 / 1919) * 100 = 39.65%. Just add half that value on top, and half that value at the bottom, then the text will remain always in the middle, and the picture will always be proportional.

I know it's a bit "hacky" and plays with knowing some data, but it seems to be working fairly well.

Comment: And now, off to look for a CSS-only solution :P

Comment: cool... I'd love a CSS only solution. I think I tried this one and failed to succeed - but maybe it will direct you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/22211990/429249

Comment: @Boaz I just updated the solution with a CSS-only option. It's a bit "cheecky", but it seems to work fine

Comment: awesome - and if you can explain why it solves the problem (so I'll learn something) - I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: I'll put it on the response as an edit, because it plays a bit with knowing the size of the picture

Comment: Done. Probably you could find a more generic solution by using `calc()`

Comment: impressive solution. Thanks! (You solved centering the text on the way as well!!!)

Answer (score 0):

you could try tweaking the jumbotron class in Bootstrap 3 just like i did for my website.

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('background-photo.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

you could change the dimension of the jumbotron depending on the dimensions you want.

```
<div row jumbotron>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work... The height is tight on the text (I can add padding to it) but the phone still gets out of screen

Comment: @Boaz did you try adding <div class="vertical-center col-md-6">text</div>? might be a solution for the text. and you can also add col-xs-12 for mobile. that might work.

Comment: If you still think your answer solves the issue - can you make a JSFiddle to "prove" it? (take the image I uploaded and slap a text on it)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about old browsers, you can try flex grid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>

        /*
            Flex Grid
            =========
        */

        #flexContainer {
            display: grid;
            gap: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Use 2 columns of the same size on each row */
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            #flexContainer {
                grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); /* Change to one column per row on smaller screens */
            }
        }

        .flexColumn {
            display: grid;
            gap: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .textFrame {
            border: solid 1px white;
            margin: 1rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .middleText {
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        .headerAndFooter {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.5rem;
        }

        #flexItem1 {
            background-image: url('../yourImage1');
            background-color: black;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top; /* When resizing the image, keep the top */
        }

        #flexItem2 {
            background-image: url('../yourImage2');
            background-color: gray;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top;
        }

        /*
            Text Size
            =========
        */

        /* Small screens (default) */
        html {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        /* Medium and Large screens */
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            html {
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        /* Large screens only */
        @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
            html {
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="flexContainer">
        <div id="flexItem1" class="flexColumn">
            <div class="textFrame">
                <div class="headerAndFooter"><h3>Item 1 Header</h3></div>
                <div class="middleText">                    
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Item 1 - Info 1
                        </li>
                       <li>
                            Item 1 - Info 2
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Item 1 - Info 3
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="headerAndFooter"><h3>Item 1 Footer</h3></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="flexItem2" class="flexColumn">      
            <div class="textFrame">
                <div class="headerAndFooter"><h3>Item 2 Header</h3></div>
                <div class="middleText">                    
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Item 2 - Info 1
                        </li>
                       <li>
                            Item 2 - Info 2
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Item 2 - Info 3
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="headerAndFooter"><h3>Item 2 Footer</h3></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output: Horizontal

[image]

Output: Vertical

[image]