# image-height not resolve output

Tags: less, web-essentials

Trying to achieve [this proposal to make a div size based on its background image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211990/2686163) I'm using Less 2.5.1 compiled by [Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) version 2.5.4 and some functions do not resolve:

**My Less File:**

```
.myClass{
    height:image-height("myUrl.png"); //<-- Do not resolve
    width:percentage(1/2); //<--Resolves 
}
```

**Resolved Css File:**

```
.myClass{
        height:image-height("myUrl.png"); //Not good
        width:50%;   //Good
    }
```

I'm having this problem with `image-height`, `image-width` and `image-size`. Not with the rest of [Misc Functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-image-size)

There's no problem resolving the image by the compiler, because it's working fine when I used it like:

```
background-image:url("myUrl.png");
```

In the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-image-size) there's a note for these methods saying:

> Note: this function needs to be implemented by each environment. It is
>   currently only available in the node environment.

In the [WebEssentials documentation](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less) it says:

> Web Essentials uses the node-less compiler and it always uses the
>   latest version

And

> NodeJS compilation -  Web Essentials uses NodeJS to run the compiler.
>   It's the fastest and most accurate compiler for LESS available.

I'm  missing something that I don't know. What does that note mean? What
 should I do?

I've create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3njpu7ep/) to share with you my goal.

Comment: What environment do you have: OS, IDE? How do you "compile" your LESS files? Documentation says that it will work only in `node environment`. It seems that you use LESS not in node environment.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirSerykh, I've updated the question referencing the compilation via WebEssentials.

Comment: Let's look at your task from another point of view. Why do you need to determine an image height in your CSS? May be there are another ways to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ensure that the path of the file (i.e. "myUrl.png") can actually be resolved by the compiler. Notice that by default, `url` paths (incl. all these `url`-related functions) are relative to the master file and not current file, see [`--relative-urls`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-relative-urls) for more details. If compiler can't find the file, the statement is left as is.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh I've updated my question with the reference to the goal, although I think it's out of scope.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I think it's resolved properly, I've update the question to notice it.

Comment: @MarioLevrero There is no real height value in their case (on link you provided). Why don't you use `height: 0;` as suggested?

Comment: I think there will be better to solve you task with image not with LESS. Could you provide you code in a snippet or on jsfiddle?

Comment: "working fine as `background-image:url("myUrl.png");`" is not yet enough (notice that this way the file is resolved by the browser relatively to the resulting css file, while `image-size` has to find image from within less file path...) Though there should be no difference if src less file and dst css file are in the same dir.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle to share with you.