# css auto adjust div height depending on background height

Tags: html, css

```
div {
    display:block;
    width:320px;
    background:url('images/cnon.jpg');
    background:contain;
}
```

Is there any way to auto-adjust `<div>` height depending on background height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what do you actually want, but if you want to make div fully aligned to background:

```
div {
    display:block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background:url('images/cnon.jpg');
    background:contain;
    margin: -10px; //Optional
}
```

Sorry if i didn't understood your question well.

Comment: if this div is empty that means the height and width will be 0!

Comment: i got a slide show ... i got different size images for responsive ... how do i use different size images in slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

if you could use jQuery you can handle it simply by checking on the `img` height then apply this height to the `div` itself

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the height of div, adjusting the padding top of the div, just need to set the css automatically.

```
.div_image{
    background:url('images/cnon.jpg');
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-top: 20%;
}
```

The padding-top is calculated by a formule.

```
(image-height[px] / image-width[px]) * container-width[%]
```

Example: `(274px / 1370px) * 100% = 20%`

With this result the padding-top need to be 20%.