# how to make the height of the div to match the height of the image without giving the div a fixed height?

Tags: html, css

this is my html markup:

```
<div class="main">

<div class="background">

</div>

</div>
```

this is the corresponding css:

```
body{margin:0;
padding:0;}

.main{width:100%;
height:auto;}

.background{width:100%;
background:url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size:cover;
}
```

clearly the above code wont show any background image on my .background div.what i want is,i don't want to give height to my background div and want the background image on that div.

Comment: Duplicated question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size

Comment: does the background-image has a ratio (size known)  and is it suppose to fill entire width ? ...  background is nothing like content, it will not fill anything but will only be drawn on background ,

Comment: Using Background images on an element does not create height, therefore you're not going to see anything unless you specify a height, or add some html content which creates height in the DOM.  You might be better off to insert your background image as an IMG element rather than a DIV with a background image.