# background image with 100% width

Tags: css

As we all know, we can create a responsive image with 100% of parent width and height according to ratio with following code. However, I would like to achieve the same effect by treating it as background image using `background-image CSS`.

It seems that I am unable to find any solution to it.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 20px;">
 <div style="width: 100%">
     <img style="width: 100%" src="http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

It seems that a lot have given answer about `background: contain` and `background: cover` and it does not work. I have provided a code snippet as follow for better clarification.

Rules: 
1) Height of div should not be specified. 
2) `background` CSS should be used (and this is why I call it as background image).
3) Background image height should auto scale according to the width.

```css
.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 20px;">
     <div class="bg-image">
 
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're looking for `background-size`.

Comment: Try somthing like `background-size: cover;`, the image will fill all the area of your div.

Comment: @SLaks neither background size nor cover fits my need

Comment: as @SLaks said, use `background-size` property

Comment: I think the missing link here is that the div has no height. Whereas an image will expand the div to fit it's height, a `background-image` will not apply any height to the div. If you want to use `background-size`, you must specify a height on your div, or put content in it to expand it.

Comment: Why are you linking a JSFiddle if you embedded the code?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution, which was mention in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size). You can do this by using the codes like below.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
   background: url(http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#wrapper > img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

By doing so, you don't need to specify any fixed height. The height of div will be equal to the height of the actual image.

Here is the updated version of your code:

```css
#wrapper {
   background: url(http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#wrapper > img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <img src="http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well i should have mention that i want to acheive about using `background-image` without specifying height of the container ...

Comment: If you don't want to specify a height to the div, or add any content, what is your reason for not using `<img>` in the first place?

Comment: @Santi code intuitive purpose. I would like to add text above the image and centering it. It could be done without using background image with absolute positioning but it just doesnt look good to me as it create long winded html and css code

Comment: You're putting your spoon down and asking us how to eat your soup with a fork. You've asked your original question all wrong. You should ask "how do I center an image below text", not "how do I avoid using <img>". There are a dozen ways to get text centered above an image without using `position: absolute;` or `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the inner div fill the parent div - hence the width and height 100%. Then just set the background size to 100% for each.

```
<div style="height:300px; width:300px;">
    <div id="bg">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #bg { 
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-image:url('http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

[Example jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eztcgt1t/2/)

Comment: He said that he wants to do this without specifying height.

Comment: the only way this question makes sense is if the parent div has some kind of height - no height = no background cos there would be no area visible.. I've provided 300px as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding of the image or the div to 100%, like this:

```
.bg-image{
    background: url('http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg')  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:100%;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, you have just to add somme properties to the css class ;)
i hope that is what you are looking for

```css
.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.greycloaktech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/url-small.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  background-position: 50% 50%;/*  */
  background-size: cover; 
  height: 43.5625rem;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:fixed;  
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 20px;">
     <div class="bg-image">
 
     </div>
    </div>
```