# Angular 4 CSS DIV background-image binding doesn't work

Tags: css, angular, typescript

template:

```
<div [style.background-image]="profileImage" ></div>
```

ts:

```
private profileImage: any;
private sanitizer:DomSanitizer
```

get photo from service:

```
this.profileImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url("+ data.photo  + ")");
```

The binding is not working. I checked Chrome Dev tools, photo is not downloaded. When refreshing the page, it is working fine, but it has to work when the value is set in service. Tried with ngStyle also, it is not working.

Plunkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/IhVGjiImyfk0F1u6cWtG?p=preview

Comment: I do not understand how refreshing makes it work? It's still within the sample process. Can you show more code and project structure?

Comment: Works fine in this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/jKMDoSEc8pq9BnhljiCw?p=preview

Comment: plunkr is working for simple case, but when data is retrieved from service it is not

Comment: Here is the plunkr which shows that it doesn't work https://plnkr.co/edit/IhVGjiImyfk0F1u6cWtG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated a bit your code in order to work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [style.background-image]="profileImage" style="width: 961px; height: 688px;"></div>
    <h2> {{message}}</h2>
  `,
})
export class App {

  profileImage: string;
  message: string;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.message = "Before async";
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await delay(2000);
    this.message = "Updating Photo";
    const url = 'https://4.bp.blogspot.com/--RBVfn6FzOI/Tq5kOxFGKEI/AAAAAAAACnM/LaiZLD0sUKY/s1600/cats.jpg';
    this.profileImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${url})`);
  }
}
```

**Changes**

**1st:** Change:

`constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer)`

into this:

`constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)`

Thus having the `sanitizer` as a member of the class in order to be accessible in `ngOnInit()`.

**2nd:** Set the dimension of the `<div>`. This will not adjust automatically to your background image size. So I set `width` and `height`. Other solutions exist, like using the aspect ratio of the image, or keeping an invisible `<img>`. These and more are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size).

**3nd:** Set the image HTTP scheme from `http` to `https` because you are receiving a warning in Plunker which serves content over `https`.

[Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2g7Rq88BtWNUsqBFMV3b?p=preview)

Comment: With quotes also not working. Check above plunkr link

Comment: @jaks sorry for that, my previous comment was stupid - `url(...) | url('...') | url("...")` are equivalent. I updated my comment with a working version.

Comment: The real problem was from the HTTP service, image was set. So it was not updating. Now put the code inside ngZone, and worked.