# Absolute siblings to have the same dimentions

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlay

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#parent {
  position: relative;
}

div#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <img src="bg.jpg" draggable="false">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm using the `<img>` [as a background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098334/5222086). I want the `#container` to be on top of the *"background"* and to have the same dimensions as the background. How may I achieve that without JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just use background-image on the div? Also, the `<img>` tag doesn't use a closing slash.

Comment: Assign `top` and `left` property with `position` `absolute`.

Comment: @Rob Hi :) Because I want the `div` to automatically adjust to the size of the background, and the closing slash was a typo ;)

Comment: @Lokesh Could you please elaborate on _"How"_?!

Comment: You got the answer ?

Comment: I posted a working answer with explanation may be it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      div#parent { position: relative; }
      div#container { position: absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:100; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); }
      img { position: relative; width: 100%; }
   </style>
 </head>
   <body>
     <div id="parent">
       <img src="bg.jpg" draggable="false"/>
       <div id="container"></div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `position:relative` to parent div but you not define the child that where the child is set behalf of it's parent, when you assign `top` and `left` `position` the child which has `position:absolute` get set `top` and `left` of the parent.

Like following

Css changes

```
div#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; /* Add this */
  left: 0; /* Add this */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Remove the absolute */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#parent {
  position: relative;
}

div#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" draggable="false" />
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your kind & correct answer, I accept @shaina's answer as he/she posted the exact same answer first :)

Comment: Happy to help you