# How do I make text appear on top of background image?

Tags: html, css

I have used this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211990

Only problem is that as soon as I enter text/content in div like this:
`<div>abc</div>`

That text appear under the image.

Code: https://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/JMxzQY

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.image {
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/d6/ef/4fd6ef1f078ca5e229ce5925c10f194a.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100.44%; /* (bg image width/ bg image height) * 100*/
}
```

```html
<div class="image">aaa</div>
```

Comment: well you have to share your code so we can show you what you did wrong

Comment: @JoshKisb https://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/JMxzQY

Comment: Do you really need to use this particular technique or would it work with `background`?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image element `position:relative` and wrap the text in an element with `position:absolute` and `top:0`

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.relative {
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  top:0;
}

.image{
  background:url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/d6/ef/4fd6ef1f078ca5e229ce5925c10f194a.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  
  height:0;
  padding-top:100.44%;  /* (bg image width/ bg image height) * 100*/
  
}
```

```html
<div class="image relative">
    <div class="text">aaa</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me : you choice is a bad strategy, because de the padding-top will always impact your content. It is not the background job.

My solution : combine height 100vh and background-size cover.

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.image{
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  background:url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/d6/ef/4fd6ef1f078ca5e229ce5925c10f194a.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image">aaa</div>
```

Comment: The goal is to adjust the height of a div to the aspect ratio of the image set as the background not to cover the viewport.