# Problem with making a background animation responsive

Tags: css

I built an animation for my background but is not responsive and I don't know how to make it.
I used Bootstrap 4 and CSS as my main design resources.

The CSS I sued as follows:

```
/* Animation GLitch */
.animation {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487174244970-cd18784bb4a4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2252&q=80");
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animation:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487174244970-cd18784bb4a4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2252&q=80");
    opacity: 0.5;
    mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
    display: block;
}
.animation:hover:before {
    animation: animate 0.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    10% {
        background-position: 5px 0;
    }
    20% {
        background-position: -5px 0;
    }
    30% {
        background-position: 15px 0;
    }
    40% {
        background-position: -5px 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: -25px 0;
    }
    60% {
        background-position: -50px 0;
    }
    70% {
        background-position: 0 -20px;
    }
    80% {
        background-position: -60px -20px;
    }
    81% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

The animation consists of 2 same pictures that create this glitch effect but I don't know how to make it responsive.

The snippest it is working here:
https://codepen.io/Jakub41/pen/abbwxWb

I tried to use the sizing but it is modifying my effect I would like to keep the same effect on all screens

Comment: Did you consider using media queries (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp&ved=2ahUKEwijz5mDtL3lAhWosKQKHaicCjQQFjAcegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2JP4RTXEyog6-UAtwzM2sY&cshid=1572212570569)?

Comment: I tried cannot find a good solution

Comment: with javascript you could do ```let width = window.innerWidth; window.onresize = fixGlitch; function fixGlitch() { document.querySelector('main').style.transform = `scale(${window.innerWidth/width});` width = window.innerWidth; }```

Comment: I'm sorry but this script does not do anything actually

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand in which way you want it to be responsive but try adding these lines after `background: url(...)` both times:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for more information about the `background-size` property.

Also the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size) might interest you.