# make div as high as background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know there are questions similar to this one, but none of them worked for me.

I have a div class with a background image:

```
    #index-box{
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: url('/static/images/bg.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Is there any way to make the `#index-box` div class so high, that the whole background image fits in?

Comment: CSS doesn’t know how high your background image is. If you know the image dimensions / aspect ratio beforehand, and you want the div to keep that same aspect ratio at any width - then go look into the _padding-bottom hack_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the aspect ratio of the image you can put all in a container with percentage padding and relative position. then another box full width and height with absolute position for the content. For the below image the original size of the image is `1280X720`, so the ratio height/width  `0.5625`:

```css
#background {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
#content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
<div id="content">some content<div>
</div>
```

Also, with similar way you always can use the image as an `img` element. so you even not need to know the aspect-ratio. like that:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img id="bg" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
<div id="content">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, thats even much more better than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size). The answers there were bad and didn't work for me

Comment: To center your text content, you'd need then to play with the absolute position?

Comment: @m3.b not nessesery. you can set `display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center` to the div

Answer (score 0):

try to apply this code:

```
#index-box{
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: url('/static/images/bg.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        object-fit:cover;
    }
```

or

```
    body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
   }
    #index-box{
            height:100%;
            border-radius: 20px;
            background: url('/static/images/bg.png') no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position:center;
        }
```